# Identify SOT23-5 IC marking 834sx inside mains power adapter

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

[image]I have SOT23-5 SMD IC with markings 834sx

[image: IC top marking]

From inside 17V power adapter:

[image: power adapter PCB]

I need help identifying that IC used in the mains power adapter.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an R1124N341B from RICOH, looking at the datasheet on page 23:

https://html.alldatasheet.com/html-pdf/201678/RICOH/R1124N341B/3651/23/R1124N341B.html

[image: Markinngs]

Comment: I don't think it's a LDO regulator. There are no capacitors connected to the part as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you I don't understand either, it is on the high voltage line and the feet are connected to the mosfet.

Comment: @nanash1 The capacitors may be on the other side of the board, a few leads are visible around the IC. Also there might be a coil and an diode on the other side. Berk could you provide a picture of the other side?

Comment: Pic send , small capacitor next to mosfet only connected to pin5 others filter capacitor, Only saw signal comes from this capacitor leg, there is no IC that produces PWM signal, I do not understand how the mosfet is driven.

Comment: If only pin 5 has a signal, it would rule the R1124N out. It also could be easily an voltage detector IC, which turns the mosfet on when power is present. I suggest you should draw an complete schematic of the highside to get a better answer than my guesses...

Comment: I understood thank you,